# Using .jpg images in asset catalogs broken in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, jpeg, xcode7, asset-catalog

In Xcode 6, it was possible to use .jpg images in asset catalogs and have the framework load the appropriate images according to the chosen size classes. However, now in Xcode 7, .jpg images simply do not show up in the assistant editor or at runtime.

I have tried renaming the image name of the asset catalog to include a .jpg extension, it works partially however only one image is ever used (the default Any/Any image, the rest of the images are ignored).

I have also tried adding the assets to the asset catalogs whilst inside an Xcode 7 environment, achieving nothing more in the end.

Our company needs to use jpg files instead of PNG files to avoid exceeding the 100 mb download limit on cellular networks for iOS apps.

Has anyone gotten the asset catalogs to work with JPEGS in any 7.x version of Xcode?

Answer (score -1):

I've tried to rename file extension from .jpg to .png and is working. But this is kind of hack.

Comment: Tried this, the images appear however the default image is always used. The asset catalog does not dynamically load another image for a different size class.

Comment: Somebody suggested on the Apple Developer Forums to change render settings from 'default' to 'original'. This solved the issue for me.